# Why doesn't the value of my boolean change in a while-loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, boolean

My algorithms book has an implementation of a linked list on Python with different methods. This is the `remove` method, but I don't fully understand the `while` loop.

This implementation relies on a `Node` class that was previously define, the class has methods such as `get.data()`,`get.next()`,`set_next()`, etc.  The list itself is a class called `UnorderedList`. `self.head` refers to the first item in the list.

The idea of this `remove` method is to traverse the list until we find the item that we want to remove. We create a `current` and a `previous` to keep track of the current item we are looking at and the one that came before.

My question has to do with the while loop. We set `found` to `False` with the intention of changing it when we find the item we are looking for. However, wouldn't the while loop change the value of `found` to `True` when we say `not found`?

I know it's a simple question, but I am having a hard time understanding why and how this while loop works since in my head `not` usually makes the boolean in its scope the opposite of what it is. Could anyone explain this to me?

btw I don't need any explanation or improvement on the current code, it's an example from the book and it all makes sense to me, I just want to understand that part.

```
def remove(self, item):
 current = self.head
 previous = None
 found = False
 while not found:
      if current.get_data() == item:
           found = True
      else:
           previous = current
           current = current.get_next()

 if previous == None:
      self.head = current.get_next()
 else:
      previous.set_next(current.get_next())
```

Comment: `not found` does not *alter* the value of `found`. It *reads* the value of `found` and gives you the opposite.

Comment: @khelwood this is where my confusion is coming from. since ```found``` is set to ```False```, my intuition is that ```not found``` would give me ```True``` and that the loop would stop running. but this is clearly not the case, so why is that? The only thing I can equate it to is when you create a variable and then say ```if variable``` and that returns ```True```  because you are basically checking if the variable exists and, well, it does. Is that the same that's going on here?

Comment: @TomServo I would be thankful if you could direct me as to how to use a debugger for this. I am self-taught and don't really use a debugger. So to answer your question, me, a self-taught curious guy trying to learn algorithms, I don't have a debugger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like I was missing part of the point of what the while-loop was trying to do. Indeed, saying `not found` means that the expression evaluates to `True`, but in this case that doesn't stop the loop. It does exactly what we want it to, it continues to run the loop. Once we find the item we are looking for, we change the value of `found` to be `True`. At that point, when we evaluate `while not found` it will yield `False`, which will get us out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`not found` is used as a conditional in the while loop, not as a statement that changes the value. You can read `while not found` as `while found == False`

Comment: that sort of makes sense. I just find it confusing because if i say ```not False``` it'll yield ```True```, right? so I am thinking since ```found = False``` ```not found``` should be ```True```? Is it similar to if I just said ```if found``` that would evaluate to ```True```? but because I am saying ```not found``` it evaluates to ```False```? It's such a confusing line of code to me